# Element does not contain all children

Tags: html, css, r, rvest

I am trying to extract text from a website with a complicated `div` structure. There are dates of events on different locations. For each day, there is a `div.day_row` element. Within these elements is a `div.column_container` with 4 elements for the different locations.

https://www.staatstheater-mainz.com/web/uebersicht/februar is the website.

Shortened example (I hope I did not delete any tags):

```
<div class="day_row" id="dr22021" style="display: block;">
            <div class="day_container"><span class="day">1</span>
                <span class="weekday">
                     Di             </span>
            </div>
            <div class="column_container">
                <div class="column" id="gh22021">
                    <span class="space_holder" id="ghsh22021" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
                    <div id="t22021kabale-und-liebe">
                        <span class="single_location">Großes Haus<br></span>
                        18:45 Einführung<br>
                        19:30-22:20 → <a href="https://www.staatstheater-mainz.com/web/veranstaltungen/schauspiel-21-22">Schauspiel</a><br>
                        <a class="titel" href="https://www.staatstheater-mainz.com/web/veranstaltungen/schauspiel-21-22/kabale-und-liebe">Kabale und Liebe</a>
                        <p>von Friedrich Schiller (1784)</p>
                        FV, PrGr IV<br>
                        <a href="http://ticket.staatstheater-mainz.de/eventim.webshop/webticket/shop?event=16539" target="_blank" class="kk_link">Karten kaufen</a><br><br><br>
                </div></div>
                <div class="column" id="kh22021">...</div>
                <div class="column" id="u1722021">...</div>
                <div class="column" id="wo22021">...</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row_space"></div>
        </div>
```

When I now try get the content of the first `div.column` within the `div.column_container`, I only get the `span` element, but NOT the `<div id="t22021kabale-und-liebe">` I am actually looking for.

Here my is my code that I tried so far:

```
content <- 
  rvest::read_html("https://www.staatstheater-mainz.com/web/uebersicht/februar")
days <- content %>% html_elements('div.day_row')
day <- days[[1]]
locations <- day %>% html_elements('div.column_container') %>% html_children()
locations[[1]] %>%
  html_children()
```

So the `html_children()` lists only the `span` within the `div.column` but it somehow hides the `<div id="t22021kabale-und-liebe">`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: That is an odd build for a website. The reason you get nothing is that it's built using JQuery.  The site builds the calendar structure, then uses JQuery to add contents to the calendar. You can try the `V8` package with `npm`. I took a stab at it without meaningful results.

Comment: Ahh, good hint. I might save the html into a file and read from there… didn’t recognized the js requests!

Comment: @Kat thanks that was the correct hint. I couldn't find a war to automate it straight forward, but I now save the website with firefox into an html and then use this html file...